# How to create a Spring Boot project with existing git repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, github

I received a take home code challenge. The git repository has a docker file and a readme file. I cloned the git repository on my local machine. I want to create a Spring Boot (Java) project with this repository. A Spring Boot project created with Spring Initializr creates a new folder, and I can't select an existing folder to use.

How do I create this project in existing git repository? I will commit and push the changes later as a part of the coding challenge.

Comment: Spring Initializr is just a quick way to get up and running, you don't **need** to use it to create a Spring Boot project, everything you can do with Spring Initializr, you can also do manually (or copy from a project created with Spring Initializr).

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a "Git" folder (with docker file and readme) and some "other" folder with spring boot project. Copy files from "other" folder to "Git" folder. Probably, you need to copy pom/build file and your Main class (with folder structure) because "Spring boot project" means exactly this two files.  After that don't forget to add copied files to Git (git add or menu in your IDE).